# Adding element at the middle of scala.collection.immutable.list in Java

Tags: scala

I am using scala immutable list in Java. I want to add element at the middle of this list. Can someone help me on this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Let `sList` be a Scala List, let `List` be the Scala List type and `42` the element to add:

```
final int half = sList.size /2;
final List<Int> first = sList.take(half);
final List<Int> second = sList.drop(half);
final List<Int> result = first.$colon$colon$colon( second.$colon$colon( 42 ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Vague answer to a vague question:

There are several ways to split an immutable list, e.g. using `take` and `drop`. From the parts (including your middle elements), you can assemble a new immutable List, e.g. using `:::`, which should be called `$colon$colon$colon` in Java, IIRC.

Please add some code if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm… you are using an immutable list. The meaning of the word "immutable" is that it can not be changed - if there is a way to add an element to the middle of such a list, it would be a bug.

**Edit**: actually, there are probably ways to add elements in such a list - probably manipulating the corresponding data at the JVM level would do the trick - but that would still be bad, because every other program that uses an immutable list expects that list to always stay the same.

Comment: yes, Immutable means that it cannot be changed but because it is immutable the add operation returns a new collection. I would like to know how that new collection can be generated?

Comment: You make a new list!  The whole point of immutable lists is you make a new one every time it changes !  (not exactly due to link list tricks, but think of it like that)