# Adding element at the middle of scala.collection.immutable.Vector in Java

Tags: java, scala, vector, insert

I am trying to use Scala's `immutable.Vector` in Java. Can anyone post an simple Java code for this?

This is what I have tried till now.

1. Tried `Vector Builder`.
2. Tried `Vector.concat(Seq<Traversable <A>>)`

Here is a sample of what I have tried:

```
Vector<Long> part1= orignal.slice(0, indexOfMid);
Vector<Long> part2 = orignal.slice(indexOfMid, orignal.size());
orignal= part2.appendFront(1L);
Vector <Traversable<Long>> vectorOfTraversables = Vector.empty();
vectorOfTraversables.appendFront(orignal.toTraversable());
vectorOfTraversables.appendFront(part1.toTraversable());
orignal= Vector.concat(vectorOfTraversables.toSeq());
```

I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
scala.collection.immutable.Vector.concat(Lscala/collection/Seq;)Lscala/collection/immutable/Vector;
```

Is there a better totally different way to do this? Or am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: You cannot change an immutable vector, so `concat` makes no sense. You need to construct a *new* vector entirely.

Comment: you mean i use a for loop again to create a new vector? that is if i cant use append at some point. is there some other way to do this?

Comment: The questions seems similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591614/adding-element-at-the-middle-of-scala-collection-immutable-list-in-java Is that some kind of homework ? If yes, use the appropriate tag.

Comment: @paradigmatic, I can't imagine this is homework. Using Scala from Java for education purpose is just cruel.

Comment: use method patch(from: Int, that: GenSeq[A], replaced: Int): Vector[A] It's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Vector<Long> part1 = original.slice(0, indexOfMid);
Vector<Long> part2 = original.slice(indexOfMid, original.size());
VectorBuilder<Long> builder = new VectorBuilder<Long>();
builder.$plus$plus$eq(part1);
builder.$plus$eq(new Long(100));
builder.$plus$plus$eq(part2);
Vector<Long> result = builder.result();
```

`VectorBuilder` provides methods that do not use `CanBuildFrom` or repeated parameters, so it's much easier to use from Java.

By the way the `NoSuchMethodError` is probably due to the fact the `concat` is a method of the companion object. Import `scala.collection.immutable.Vector$` and try this:

```
Vector$.MODULE$.concat(vectorOfTraversables.toSeq());
```

Comment: I'd have used `splitAt` instead of `slice`. Also, why are you starting the slice at `1`?

Comment: @Daniel, yep starting at 1 was a typo - now corrected. Fair point about `splitAt`, I just didn't feel like dealing with Scala tuples from the Java side.

Answer (score 1):

If you see a [NoSuchMethodError](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html), or any other error that descends from [LinkageError](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/LinkageError.html), it means that your code was compiled against a different version of a library than is in your classpath.

This is somewhat uncommon with Java libraries, but it's incredibly common in Scala, where binary compatibility is quite difficult to achieve—primarily because of traits.

Make sure your runtime classpath contains the exact same Scala version as your compile classpath, and you should at least get further.*

***EDIT:** But, then again, you won't get very far without a LOT of pain.  If you really need to use a Scala collection from Javaland, I think your best best is probably to write an interface in Java, and implement it from Scala.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but i just have one version of scala library on my machine. Any other clues? not to solve the problem but an alternate solution for my task?